# How to have "install" python locally, touching nothing but a single directory?

Tags: python, deployment, installation

I'd like to "install" a version of Python locally, which doesn't touch anything on the system (Windows in this case) except the directory I extract it into. I would run it by specifying that particular `python.exe`.

This is for the end-user. Essentially, I want to be able to extract a Python into a directory and start using it immediately, without requiring the user to even know that my program is using Python. I'm looking into py2exe and PyInstaller as well, but I'd like to know if this option is viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it certainly sounds like a viable option. As far as I know, the only "interaction" the official Python installer has with Windows is to add registry keys associating `.py` and `.pyw` files with the proper executables and possibly modifying the `PATH` variable. As long as the user has the correct `.dll` files to which the `.exe`'s are linked, you could just zip up `c:\Python33` or whichever version you're using and distribute that with your application. Before you do that, though, clone the directory and go through `c:\clonedPython\libs\site-packages` and get rid of any modules that aren't required for your application. Don't delete any necessary dependencies!

[Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) is a possibility, but there may be some issues with certain modules not working properly, and it's not available yet for Python 3.3 (3.2.1 is the latest version, as well as 2.7.3), so if you have version-dependent syntax that might not be the best choice.

Comment: the issue is that my folder is 300 megabytes or so, it has a lot of stuff in there. if I try to install the same version of python on my system, it just asks me to reconfigure the existing one.. i guess i can do a clean install on another machine then copy it over to mine to work with

Comment: @Claudiu - you can also go through the `C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages` directory and delete any directories/files for modules that aren't needed for your application.

Comment: True, but I need those for other things =).

Comment: @Claudiu - see my edited answer above - you should clone the `c:\pythonXX` directory first, then delete any modules that aren't needed for your application distribution.

Comment: ah yeah, definitely an option. i'm checking out portablepython now, but if that doesn't work out i'll try this. i'm using python 2.6 so shouldn't be any version issues

Comment: I ended up doing a hybrid. Copying my python 2.6 install , taking the modules I want, then using the .dlls from PortablePython to make it work, which it seems I could also have done using [@LQian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15685854/15055)'s approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) - it is a version of python modified to do exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 for Portable Python, used it around 2 years ago, awesome tool ;-)

Comment: but, no Python 3.3 version yet :(

Comment: is it possible to install additional modules into it?

Answer (score 1):

When you install python on Windows, select "for current user only" rather than "for all users of this system" when you're asked. And select the installation target to some custom directory, e.g. D:\mypython\

This kind of installation will package all necessary binaries and DLL files (e.g. msvcr90.dll) to this specified dir, with which you can deploy easily to another system (with same CPU-bit and operating system).

(I got this solution from a Chinese website http://www.oschina.net/question/23734_13481 - comment 1)